# Scalaz implementation of Semigroup using advanced Scala features

Tags: scala, traits, implicits, monoids, semigroup

I was digging through the implementation of [Monoid](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.2.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Monoid.scala)s in Scalaz. I came across the [|+|](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/SemigroupSyntax.scala#L7) operator that is supposed to come *out of the box* if you define the *append* operation on Monoid. The definition of this operator is in *SemigroupSyntax*. That class gets to Monoid through [Semigroup](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.1.x/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Semigroup.scala).

After examining these three classes I have one major question - How exactly is the comment from *SemigroupSyntax* achieved `` /** Wraps a value `self` and provides methods related to `Semigroup` */ ``

There is some magic with implicits, calling `.this` on trait and more in the *SemigroupSyntax* that I honestly don't understand.

I would love if someone could take the time to enlighten me.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

I am keen to understand the workings of this class:

```
package scalaz
package syntax

/** Wraps a value `self` and provides methods related to `Semigroup` */
final class SemigroupOps[F] private[syntax](val self: F)(implicit val F: Semigroup[F]) extends Ops[F] {
  ////
  final def |+|(other: => F): F = F.append(self, other)
  final def mappend(other: => F): F = F.append(self, other)
  final def ⊹(other: => F): F = F.append(self, other)
  ////
}

trait ToSemigroupOps  {
  implicit def ToSemigroupOps[F](v: F)(implicit F0: Semigroup[F]) =
    new SemigroupOps[F](v)

  ////
  ////
}

trait SemigroupSyntax[F]  {
  implicit def ToSemigroupOps(v: F): SemigroupOps[F] = new SemigroupOps[F](v)(SemigroupSyntax.this.F)

  def F: Semigroup[F]
  ////
  def mappend(f1: F, f2: => F)(implicit F: Semigroup[F]): F = F.append(f1, f2)

  ////
}
```

And its call site in Semigroup:

```
val semigroupSyntax = new scalaz.syntax.SemigroupSyntax[F] { def F = Semigroup.this }
```

Comment: If you paste the code that you don't understand it would be a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most disorienting thing here is that there's actually two routes to getting operations on object.

First route, the default one, is by `import scalaz.syntax.semigroup._`. It adds operators for all implicitly available `Semigroup` instances.

1. Any `Semigroup` instance creates an implementation of `SemigroupSyntax` for itself, defining its `F` method in terms of `this`.
2. In scalaz/syntax/package.scala, there's a `syntax` singleton object that extends `Syntaxes` trait. It is the first part of import definition.
3. In scalaz/syntax/Syntax.scala, there's a `semigroup` singleton object within `Syntaxes` trait used in `syntax`, which extends `ToSemigroupOps`. We're importing contents of this object, containing only the implicit conversion. The purpose of conversion is to capture implicitly provided `Semigroup` instance and construct a wrapper, `SemigroupOps`, which contains all the operations.

Second route is a shortcut by `import [your_semigroup_instance].semigroupSyntax._`, a call site in `Semigroup` you're listed. It adds operators to a particular type, for which `Semigroup` instance is.

1. `semigroupSyntax` is an anonymous implementation of `SemigroupSyntax` trait, which `F` method is defined to be a particular instance of `Semigroup`.
2. `SemigroupSyntax` trait itself, like `ToSemigroupOps`, offers an implicit conversion to `SemigroupOps`, but instead of capturing implicitly provided instance, it uses its `F` method. So we get operators on type `F`, using particular `Semigroup` typeclass implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate explanation. I don't really understand it even though I read it several times but I have some simple questions. 
How do the library designers benefit in your opinion from all this misdirection? Is it about code extensibility? Because in my mind this thing is hell to maintain.

Comment: Design is actually quite modular: one file per typeclass, another one for syntax, and one-liner registration in Syntax.scala (plus, maybe, some instances in `scalaz.std`). Code for type class and its syntax wrappers follows the common pattern, and, while not used in Scalaz, there's [code-generation compiler plugin](https://github.com/mpilquist/simulacrum) for it. While wrapping mechanism itself, designed to closely resemble Haskell coding practices, can look complicated, library architecture remains clear and loosely coupled.